# Creating custom validator for image uploading at Nest.js with class-validator package

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I want to validate the mimetype of file at Nest.js. But i can't.

```js
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  @Post('upload_profile_photo')
  async uploadProfilePhoto(@UploadedFile() image: UploadImageDto) {
    return image;
}
```

UploadImageDto.ts

```js
import { IsImageFile } from '../validators/IsImageFile';

export class UploadImageDto {
  @Validate(IsImageFile)
  mimetype: string;
}
```

IsImageFile.ts

```js
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: false, name: 'image' })
export class IsImageFile implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(mimeType: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    // nothing is written on the console
    console.log(mimeType);

    const acceptMimeTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

    const fileType = acceptMimeTypes.find((type) => type === mimeType);

    if (!fileType) return false;

    return true;
  }

  defaultMessage(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): string {
    return 'The file type was not accepted.';
  }
}
```

My custom decorator doesn't execute. Anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function which does the validation, and use it in annotation above the property you wish to validate, like so :

```
import { ValidationOptions, registerDecorator } from 'class-validator';

export function IsImageFile(options?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options,
      validator: {
        validate(mimeType) {
          const acceptMimeTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];
          const fileType = acceptMimeTypes.find((type) => type === mimeType);
          return !fileType;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

```
export class UploadImageDto {
  @IsImageFile({message: invalid mime type received})
  mimetype: string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But again it doesn't execute the IsImageFile method. Did you try that?

Comment: i did.. 
if you have a git link to the project, i can try it out

Answer (score 3):

You can use in-built file validator

```
@UploadedFile(
    new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
            new FileTypeValidator({fileType: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/}),
        ],
    })
)
```

Note: File type is `RegExp`.

See: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#validators

Comment: `ParseFilePipe` remove from `@nestjs/common`. You can create custom pipe for this.

@user15721538

Comment: this worked for  me   @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
          new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: /(jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$/ }),
        ],
      }),
    )

Comment: The Regex pattern is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ParseFilePipeBuilder` to solve this problem.

```
 @UploadedFile(
  new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
    .addFileTypeValidator({
      filetype: 'png',
    })
    .addFileTypeValidator({
      filetype: 'jpeg',
    })
    .addMaxSizeValidator({
      maxSize: 1000000, // just to you know it's possible.
    })
    .build({
      exceptionFactory(error) {
        throw new HttpException(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      },
    }),
)
file: Express.Multer.File,
```

Answer (score 1):

If u need to validate the type of upload file u can using FileInterceptor, it had fileFilter function to help u catch files when requests come in. The first problem is how it can handle the response to FE. After a minute I saw we can use MulterError to handle this Error in the response. This's my code hope it can help.

```
  @Post('addOne')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('image', {
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.originalname.match(/^.*\.(jpg|webp|png|jpeg)$/))
          cb(null, true);
        else {
          cb(new MulterError('LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE', 'image'), false);
        }
      },
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public/test'));
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
      }),
    }),
  }
```

If u need to validate field must have file when request. We can use ParseFilePipe method in UploadedFile decorator, it had fileIsRequired to help check it.

```
@UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        fileIsRequired: true,
      }),
    )
```